# Asking tikz code for this diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-styles, tikz-trees, tikz-cd

Can someone provide me the tikz code for the following diagram?

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks so much

Comment: Take a look at `tikz-cd` package.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You should take a look at the `tikz-cd` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=0em]
& \text{Intermediate fields}\\[-4ex]
& \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5})\ar[d, dash]\ar[dr, dash]\ar[dl, dash]\\
\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}) & \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}) & \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{15})\\
& \mathbb{Q}\ar[u, dash]\ar[ur, dash]\ar[ul, dash]\\
\end{tikzcd}\quad
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=1.5em]
& \text{Subgroups}\\[-4ex]
& \{\iota\}\ar[d, dash]\ar[dr, dash]\ar[dl, dash]\\
\{\iota,\alpha\} & \{\iota,\tau\} & \{\iota,\beta\}\\
& \{\iota,\alpha,\tau,\beta\}\ar[u, dash]\ar[ur, dash]\ar[ul, dash]\\
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Following the advice given by the very good users in the comments here there is my short proposal.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[bb = boondox]{mathalfa}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
 & \overset{\text{Intermediate fields}}{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 3, \sqrt 5)} \arrow[d, no head] \arrow[ld, no head] \arrow[rd, no head] & &  & & \overset{\text{Subgroups}}{\{\iota\}} \arrow[ld, no head] \arrow[d, no head] \arrow[rd, no head] & \\
\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 3)\arrow[rd, no head] & \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}) \arrow[d, no head] & \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{15}) \arrow[ld, no head] &  & \{\iota,\alpha\} \arrow[rd, no head] & \{\iota,\tau\} \arrow[d, no head]  & \{\iota,\beta\} \arrow[ld, no head] \\
 & \mathbb{Q}&   &  &  & \{\iota,\tau, \alpha, \beta\}   &                      
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```